# How to apply CSS to dynamically generated PHP database results

Tags: php, mysql, css

I'm trying to work out how I can break up a large block of text with CSS or PHP into paragraphs or line breaks. My PHP script queries a MYSQL database and returns a random number of entries (sentences) depending on the number selected by user. The results are echoed out in one large paragraph.

Is there anyway I can break up this one paragraph into smaller paragraphs? I don't want a line break after each result.

I can do this with fixed text in HTML with `<p>` tags or `<br>` tags but how can I do it with dynamically generated results when I have no idea how long the block of text will be? I'm quite new to PHP. Any suggestions appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="sentence"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sn=$_POST['numberofsentences'];


$query="SELECT line FROM `sentence` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT $sn";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
// do something with $row. The following echos the results and adds a space after each sentence.
echo $row['line'], "&nbsp";
}

// Close the database connection
mysql_close();

 ?>
```

Comment: One quick and easy way would be to set a static amount of sentences per paragraph like 4 or 5 and use that in your loop like so: 
$count = 0;
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
// do something with $row. The following echos the results and adds a space after each sentence.
echo $row['line'], "&nbsp";
if ($count <= 4) {
    echo '<br />';
    $count = 0;
} else {
$count++;
}
}

Comment: Hi. I tried that and I get each sentence (database result) echoed out on a separate line. I need them grouping into 4 or 5 sentences per paragraph. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I mean to put: if ($count >= 4). Try that! Here, I'll put it in as an answer formatted.

Comment: You're a genius! That's exactly what I wanted. Do you know how I can add three or four spaces before the first sentence in each paragraph (like an indent?) Thank you.

Comment: HEhe no prob. Check the answer I posted...It has two '<br />' tags now in between each paragraph.

Comment: you're quick! extra spaces (indent) would be better but will accept spaces between paragraphs. Thanks

Comment: Oh I see, yeah I guess I misunderstood your request.  There are several ways to accomplish that, I guess the easiest would be to use multiple non-breaking spaces (&nbsp;). Let's see...

Comment: Can anyone tell me where I'm going worng here? Am now getting error on line 49 which is.....while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )    the error says: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs. Only happens when page first loads. also happened with blank data submitted but sorted that with javascript validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick and easy way would be to set a static amount of sentences per paragraph like 4 or 5 and use that in your loop like so:

```
$count = 0; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    // do something with $row. The following echos the results and adds a space after each sentence. 
    echo $row['line'], "&nbsp"; 
    if ($count >= 4) { 
        echo '<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'; 
        $count = 0; 
    } else { 
        $count++; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only thing you can do is use HTML (and optionally CSS) to do this.

Also you have some problems with your example code. '&nbsp' should have a `;` at the end. I assume you mean `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and not `mysql_fetch_array()` since you're referencing the `$row` array with a string index rather than numerical?

```
$results = 0;
$max_results = 26;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $results++;
  echo $row['line'] . "&nbsp;";

  if ($results % max_results == 0)
    echo "<br /><br />";
}
```

This will print out up to 25 space-separated results per line. This is very crude, but will work in the browser. Ideally, you should add supporting HTML tags such as html, body, etc...

Also, as a side note: I understand that you are still learning, but please please PLEASE remember that whenever you accept any sort of external input in your SQL strings, you must must MUST sanitize them first. What if `$_POST['numberofsentences']` was equal to `0;DROP DATABASE db;`?

If you're expecting the POST variable to be an integer, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` followed by `intval()`.

---

**Edit:** I didn't want to remove the mistake I made in my post about dot vs. comma since it's referenced in the comments below, but it seems it may cause some confusion if I leave it in here. You can `echo string1 . string2` or `echo string1, string2`. These both give the same output but work quite differently under-the-hood. To see the original post just look at the history.

Comment: `echo $foo , $bar;` is perfectly fine, and faster than `echo $foo . $bar;`

Comment: Thanks for that. Will be sure to santitize against SQL injections. Also, why do I need to put dot instead of comma. It works with dot. I realize this is probably a very naive question. ta

Comment: @user1022772 They both work. The dot will concatenate multiple strings into 1, and then the `echo()` function will print the single string. With a comma, you are passing several parameters to `echo()`, which then loops through the parameters and prints them sequentially. I have always used a dot, but as AlienWebuy commented, the comma is fine too, and apparently faster. In reality, I don't think comma vs. dot has a significant performance difference for most modest PHP applications. Use whichever you're more comfortable with.

Comment: @Ozzah Actually, echo is not a function but a language construct. It is highly discouraged to use parenthesis with echo. (e.g. echo('string'); should really be echo 'string';)   =)

Comment: Thanks for your help on this one. That makes it a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$host     = "localhost"; // Host name 
$username = "";          // Mysql username 
$password = "";          // Mysql password 
$db_name  = "db";        // Database name 
$tbl_name = "sentence";  // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sn           = $_POST['numberofsentences'];
$s_count_orig = $s_count = 1; // Sentence counter
$p_count      = 1;            // Paragraph counter
$per_para     = 4;            // 4 sentences per paragraph
$paras        = array();      // Array to hold the paragraphs
$para         = array();      // Array to hold the sentences

$query  = "SELECT line FROM `sentence` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT $sn";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    // do something with $row. The following echos the results and adds a space after each sentence.

    // If there is room in the paragraph array for a sentence...
    if($s_count <= $per_para) {

        // Add the sentence to the array
        $para[$p_count] = $row['line'];

        // Next sentence
        $s_count++;
    }
    else {
        // We have a full paragraph, add it to our master array
        $paras[] = $para[$p_count];

        // Next paragraph
        $p_count++;

        // Reset sentence counter
        $s_count = $s_count_orig;
    }
}

// Iterate our master array of paragraphs
foreach($paras as $p){

    // Echo each paragraph, and each sentence in each paragraph separated by two spaces
    echo '<p>' . implode('&nbsp;&nbsp;',$p) . '</p>';
}

// Close the database connection
mysql_close();

 ?>
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this and got error message: Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed.

Answer (score 0):

Untested

```
define('NB_SENTENCE_PER_PARAGRAPH', 5);

// after the query...

$paragraphs = array();
$i = 0;

// prepare data

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $index = floor(%i / NB_SENTENCE_PER_PARAGRAPH);

  if (!isset($paragraphs[$index]))
    $paragraphs[$index] = array();

  $paragraphs[$index][] = $row['line'];
  $i++;
}

// display

foreach ($paragraphs as $sentences)
{
  echo '<p>'.implode('&nbsp;', $sentences).'</p>';
}
```

Note that it is generally a good idea to separate data retrieving from display (offers more flexibility).